# VS code on mac can't find pandas module

Tags: python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code on mac for my python homework. I installed pandas, numpy, and a few other libraries but only importing pandas gives the following errors:

```
File "/Users/Li/Documents/Resources/lynda/recsys/RecSys-Materials/test.py", line 1, in <module>

import pandas as pd

ImportError: No module named pandas
```

[import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLyqy.png)

I double checked my installation of pandas:

```
pip install pandas

Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.25.1)

Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.7.4)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.17.1)

Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2018.9)

Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.11.0)
```

and numpy:

```
pip install numpy

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.17.1)

VS Code setting: python select interpreter: current: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

I was wondering which part I did incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Remove the installation and reinstall with [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)

Comment: Come on, he is talking about VScode...

Answer (score 0):

The errors are maybe caused due to unable to detect the library from the path.